# Civil War - what triggers this?

Tags: civilization-2

I've played more games of Civ2 than I should have, but only once or twice have I seen a civilisation split in to two part - something like loyalists and rebels.  In practise, civ2 just splits off some cities and gives them to a new civilisation.

Does anyone know what triggers this rare event?  Does anyone have a screen shot so I can reminisce!?

additional link: https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/civil-war.462908/  An old post now (aren't we all..., ho hum).  They discuss civil war, one poster says it happened in Civ2, someone else says the original Civ (which I did play 20-25 years ago, but that definitely wasn't what I was thinking of).

Comment: Are you certain it was Civ2 and not Civ3 or later?

Comment: I've played Civ3 too, but I'm about 95% certain it was Civ2.  It was a very rare occurrence, I must have played a couple hundred games of Civ2.  Have you seen something like that in Civ3?  I've not played anything after Civ3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the civfanatics forum](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/how-do-you-split-a-civilization.6269/), these are the factors that let a civilization split:

- You, another player or even the barbarians conquer the capital of that civilization
- Said civilization is ahead of you (or the respective attacker) in power

You should be able to recreate that with these information.

Comment: A third criteria I remember- there must be fewer than 7 civilizations remaining in the game (so the rebels have a colour to spawn as).

Comment: Thanks npst - a great find.  Hmmm, I think my brother still has Civ2 installed, I must demonstrate splitting a Civ to him!